# How to get steam to recognise previous files when my HDD does not match the space requirements

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

So I installed GTA V the other day, but for some reason when it was done, it still came up with "Install" instead of "Play" so I tried to reinstall but my HDD was too full.

I went to the directory it installed under and all the files seem to be there, but obviously since my HDD is too full I cant validate the game. So far I've tried re-adding the steam directory and restarting steam, didn't work. I tried steam://validate/271590 in run, didn't work.

So is there a way I can verify the game without having to delete and reinstall the game (it took 2 whole days to complete so that's last resort for me)

P.S. Just incase you need to know i have 2 steam directories E:/Steam and D:/Steam GTA V is installed under D:/Steam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steam seems to think that the game is not installed. To make Steam discover the existing files, hit "Install" and then tell it to install into the directory where your files have already been installed. Steam should then verify the existing files and download all missing files.

Note, though, that Steam will delete all files it does not recognize or cannot verify. It is unlikely that this should happen to you, as you claim that all existing files have also been obtained via Steam, but it is a possibility. However, there isn't really anything you can do about that as Steam will refuse to let you run a game with unverified files.

Comment: The problem with this is it tells me that I don't have enough hard drive space, which i don't (now that ive installed the game)

Comment: @Sithjjf My guess is that Steam will try to check whether the hard drive space is available before checking whether the game is already on there. One solution I can think of would be to free up some space, e.g. by temporarily moving some files to a USB drive and then try again.

Comment: Yeah i ended up doing this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it installed in steam then go to 
Library

> right click gta5 
>   go to the last option(properties)
>   Go to local files which is the 3rd tab from the left 
>   Click on View integrity of game cache

Comment: Verify game cache is blacked out, i guess because its not actually installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check both directories for any game files relating to gta5 
Go to ProgramsX86

> Steam 
>   Steam powered
>   The next step I think you should go to the games folder and see from there 
>   Else you would just have to reinstall

Personally I would keep just one steam directory so that it would be easier to find things when problems crop up.

Comment: The files are there i just dont know how to get steam to see that they are there.Tbh that would be easier, if my E drive wasn't full ;( that was the whole reason for installing it onto my D drive (that and D has faster read/write speeds)